# Administrator account in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, passwords, user-accounts, administrator

I have a Windows Vista (Home Premium) machine with a unique user for which the owner forgot the password. I have physical access to the machine.

I gave a try with the Ophcrack Live CD, but it couldn't find the password. Ophcrack showed me that two more hidden accounts exist (Administrator and Guest), with no password associated.

I tried to boot the machine in safe mode (with or without command prompt). Plenty of tutorials claim I should be able to select the Administrator account for login by using safe mode, but I still see the unique old user in the logon screen.

Is there a way I can login to this machine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the **[Offline NT Password and Registry Editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/)** and reset (clear) the password.

Comment: it always does ... and you're more than welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

Boot from the Windows Vista DVD, choose Repair, and then either do a system restore, or go to a command prompt. The command prompt might let you do:

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```

which should enable the administrator account.

Comment: Don't have a Vista DVD. They didn't give it together with the laptop :(

Comment: Aha - then log in and create a boot disk. Oh no. Wait. Err....