# To enable the administrator account from the standard user account

Tags: user-accounts, administrator

I have exactly the same problem as was already described ([by Rajendra Rathore](https://superuser.com/questions/454860/is-there-any-way-to-enable-administrator-account-from-an-limited-user-account-in)): "... I removed my user account from administrators group and my default administrator account was disabled by default. So now i am unable to perform any administrative task. Is there any way to add my user account in administrator group  OR Enable default administrator account in windows 7"

I heard that it could be fixed by Hiren Boot CD - I have it but I don't know how to use it. Could you kindly describe the whole procedure step by step.

Comment: In Windows XP days, booting in safe mode would fix this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get back-to-work with a Windows 7 PC that has no admin account?](http://superuser.com/questions/239130/how-to-get-back-to-work-with-a-windows-7-pc-that-has-no-admin-account) also see [Administrator account in Windows Vista](http://superuser.com/questions/86478/administrator-account-in-windows-vista?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Recovery Console from the OS install disk (or should be available from Startup Repair or F8 menu) you should be able to add your account back to administrator group

- net localgroup Administrators *yourusername* /add